# How to launch our installed app from google assistant

Tags: android

Can we launch our installed application from Google assistant? Let's say the user has an application "POC" installed on my android device and if a user says "Open POC app" on Google Assistant (i.e after "Ok Google"), my POC app should open.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: So, Suppose in the application, there are several screens, each with some purpose. If User says "Purpose 1 " application's first screen should get opened..What to do for these kinds of scenarios?

Comment: Please don't add information by commenting your own question. If it matters to the question, you can [edit] it.

Comment: "i.e." and "e.g." are not the interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything on your behalf. Google Assistant will open your app on saying "OK Google, Open MYAPP".